# Play 1.2.4 Mobile and PC design on the same app

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework

I am a new developer in Play world! For a project I need to have a mobile and desktop version. But I don't know how to!!

- Create 2 applications, share the model..;
- Create a mobile controller to separate the desktop views against the mobile views

I have no idea of how to make this properly. I know the responsive design but I can't use it on this project.

Thanks

PS: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case I would have a look at a framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). With the twitter bootstrap you can use ONE set of view templates for both desktop and mobile. There is also a framework called [Kickstrap](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/) and a few others.

But on the other hand, if you want to develop some sort of 'backend' or 'admin' application (you still CAN use twitter bootstrap, but you might have a look at frameworks like Sencha (EXT JS and Touch) or Kendo UI.

What ever you choose, Play will enable you to develop the serverside as it should be (RESTful), so the choice for the frontend can change in time, but you app architecture will be fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Either one is okay. As they are essentially the same thing, 2 set of routes/controllers/views plus 1 set of domain models.

If you are using [my play clone](https://github.com/greenlaw110/play/tree/v1.2), then you can simplified it to 1 set of domain model + 1 set of routes/controllers + 2 set of views, as you can do something like follows:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
   ...
   @OnApplicationStart
   public static class ViewRouter extends Job {
        Controller.registerTemplateNameResolver(new ITemplateNameResolver(){
            @Override
            public String resolveTemplateName(String templateName) {
                return UserAgent.isMobile() ? "mobile/" + templateName : templateName;
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Thus you just put your mobile views under `app/views/mobile` and all others still remain in `app/views`, the template will be loaded dynamically based on the request's user agent, if it's coming from a mobile device then `app/views/mobile/..` version get loaded otherwise, the normal view will be loaded.

Comment: green, it's possible to explain more the implementation of your solution?